# Debian - Rationale for "Recommended" Packages?

Tags: debian, apt, debian-policy

**Aptitude** flagged a package for upgrade recently, and I noticed that a package that was not currently installed was listed as "Recommended." In this case, it was an interesting looking font package.

**Question:** Is there a ***central resource*** I could access that discusses the rationale behind specific packages' "Recommended" packages? What I am envisioning is a list of packages, whereby I could choose a package, see what packages it, in turn, recommends, and then find rationale behind each of said recommendations.

I realize that these are developer decisions, but the ***specific rationale*** behind such decisions would be both useful and illuminating.

TIA!

Answer (score 3):

From the [Debian maintainer's guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html#control):

> Recommends
>
> Use this for packages that are not strictly necessary but are
> typically used with your program. When a user installs your program,
> all front-ends will probably prompt them to install the recommended
> packages. aptitude and apt-get install recommended packages along with
> your package by default (but the user can disable this behavior). dpkg
> will ignore this field.

Check also `Suggests` in the very same page.

Comment: Interesting information, to be sure, but there is no "rationale" included. I could have emphasized this in the OP - will update that now...

Comment: @Digger "not strictly necessary but are typically used with" **IS** the rationale.  It's deliberately broad and vague so that package maintainers don't have to waste time justifying every little decision they make.  Anything that is "strictly necessary" would be in a Depends: line, not Recommends, because the package won't work without it.   Recommends is for packages that are very useful but their absence won't actually break the package you're installing.  Similarly, a Suggests: line is for packages that provide some minor enhancements or that are sometimes used with the package.

Answer (score 3):

[Eduardo Trápani’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/686503/86440) explains the general use-case for “Recommends”. For specific information about a given package’s recommendations, look at the package description; in many cases, the rationale is given there.

For example, my own [`heroes`](https://packages.debian.org/heroes) package has two “Recommends”, explained as follows in its description:

> You should install the `heroes-sound-effects` package if you want sound effects,
> and the `heroes-sound-tracks` package if you want background music in the game.

Comment: Stephen Kitt, your example is, unfortunately, indeed a rarity. What I am envisioning is a **central** resource where said I could find your mentioned information concerning the `heroes` package along with that associated with thousands of other packages...

Comment: If package maintainers don’t document this in their packages, I doubt they’d go and update some other location with the missing information... Package metadata is the central resource IMO (and all packages’ metadata for a given suite and architecture ends up in a single, “central”, place, the `Packages` file).

Comment: I suppose that, if there were a way to parse said rationale-related information from said package metadata, the resultant listing may be as close as one could get to my ask of a **central resource**.

Comment: What would the benefit be of doing that? If you want to know why a specific package recommends others, isn’t the package metadata the best place to look?